# Laravel 4 prefix variable routing

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am trying to pass the username via the url.

```
site.tld/{username}/account
```

So i have this entry here in my routes

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => '{username}'), function($username)
{
    $user = User::whereUsername($username)->first();
    if(!is_null($user))
    {
        Route::get('portfolio', 'PortfolioController@getIndex');
        Route::get('profile', 'ProfileController@getIndex');
        ....
    }
}
```

i get the following error.

```
Object of class Illuminate\Routing\Router could not be converted to string
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`Route::group()` does not work the same way as Route::method(), the closure is executed during the route listing procedure and what is passed to it is the router, not your parameter:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => '{username}'), function($router) { ... });
```

So you are basically doing:

```
$user = User::whereUsername($router)->first();
```

That's why it says

```
Object of class Illuminate\Routing\Router could not be converted to string
```

But you may user a filter:

```
Route::filter('age', function($route, $request)
{
    if (! User::whereUsername($route->parameter('username'))->first())
    {
        App::abort(404);
    }
});

Route::group(array('prefix' => '{username}', 'before' => 'age'), function($username)
{
    Route::get('portfolio', 'PortfolioController@getIndex');
    Route::get('profile', 'ProfileController@getIndex');
});
```